# Table name of model changes per week

Tags: loopbackjs

Trying to expose data from our database where the tables are created per week. each week table name would be table_data_wk_09102017_09162017 etc..
My model definition remains the same, but data is split per week.
I have created my model using loopback, trying to figure on how to template the name of the table, please let me know if there is way to resolve this?